# SQL Query - Rank showing only 1 rank for all records

Tags: sql, sql-server, ranking

I am trying to perform ranking based on some calculation of already existing columns. I tried using the SQL RANK() function however it is showing the result as 1 for all entries even if the value of the order by (score column) is different. Please see the details below:

1. **qu_point** and **ti_points** are calculated columns
2. **score** column is again a derived column, however, simply sum of two columns mentioned in point 1.

I have used the SQL query as follow:

```
use EFR_DB
GO

select d.serial, d.question_set_id, d.correct_answers, d.total_questions, d.time_taken_seconds, q.total_time_in_secs,
(cast(d.correct_answers as float)/d.total_questions) as qu_point, ((q.total_time_in_secs-d.time_taken_seconds)/q.total_time_in_secs) as ti_point,
(((cast(d.correct_answers as float)/d.total_questions)*2) + ((q.total_time_in_secs-d.time_taken_seconds)/q.total_time_in_secs)) as score,

rank() over (partition by d.question_set_id order by score)

from daily_quiz_record d join Question_set q 
on q.question_set_id=d.question_set_id
```

Please help me how can I do the raking which is partitioned by **question_set_id** and **ranked** on the basis of the **score**.

Screenshot attached for your reference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6y8uZ.png)

Comment: Try using ROW_NUMBER() instead of RANK()

Comment: I cannot use Row_Number as I am required to update the same values to the main table from where the data has been fetched.

In addition to it, row_number() will not be partitioned by another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t use an alias defined in the `select` clause in the same clause. I suppose that one of your table has a column called `score`, otherwise your query would error - so this existing column is being used for ordering instead of the computed value.

Since your expression is lengthy, it is simpler to turn the query to a subquery, and rank in the outer query:

```
select 
    t.*,
    rank() over(partition by question_set_id order by score) rn
from (
    -- your existing query (without rank)
) t
```

Comment: This code along with the explanation worked for me. It helped me understand the logic behind.

You are also correct - I have a column named 'score' in one of the table, which is not a calculated column.